# Calculating summary stats for data frames containing mixed data types

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, statistics

been scratching my head on this, but I have a data set from a CSV that's like

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3.1 1
2   3   2   N/A
3   N/A 3.5 3
4   3   5   5
5   4   6   2.5
```

I'm using `read.csv`, but the resultant data frame converts the columns that contain "N/A" into type "chr")

I'm using `apply(result,2,mean)` to calculate column means but I get the error: "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Is there a simple way to do what I'm trying to do, instead of looping through the data frame column by column, turning them into lists, converting to numeric, then cbinding them back together?

Comment: Try setting the argument `na.strings = c("NA", "N/A")` in `read.csv` when you first read the CSV in. That should make sure missing values are properly treated as missing, and the column is read in as numeric.

Comment: @Marius thank you kindly! I was pounding my head hours, googling, dreading having to write an embedded loop when in the back of my mind, I knew I was missing something!

Comment: It's best to make sure all your data types are right as soon as you read the data in, getting everything set up right at the start makes writing all the following code much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Marius the solution was simply to add parameter `na.string = c("NA","N/A")` to the end of the read.csv function.

I hope this helps someone!